# Filling up ListView With a Cursor in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to fill up a ListView in Android with a Cursor. For that, I made an object of ArrayAdapter and passed it type as Cursor. I didn't get the result I wanted. I just want to know that am I doing it correct way or is it wrong? And if its wrong can any one suggest me to do this task. I want to display all the rows in the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this nice [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Note that you need to pass a `List<YourDataModelClass>` to `ArrayAdapter`'s constructer. (It may simple be `List<String>`) Here is what I mean:

```
List<YourDataModelClass> values = datasource.getAllYourDataModelClass();

ArrayAdapter<YourDataModelClass> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<YourDataModelClass>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
listView.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

`datasource.getAllYourDataModelClass();` above is the place where Cursor is saved as a `List` of class you designed.

Hope this helps.